# have ubuntu on clean SSD want to add windows

Tags: ssd

Starting from total ignorance ... lost my old hard drive, placed new SSD and installed Ubuntu ... would also like to run windows.
I installed Ubuntu 1st because I couldn't install Ws
Could someone explain the procedure as they would to a 4 yr old (ie very elementary).
I don't understand how to partition a disc.
When I tried to download W7 again they would not recognize my product key on the computer. 
What's the best, safest way to get around that
Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't really a question about Ubuntu...  It would be better on superuser.com.

Comment: If a newer Computer with product key in UEFI, you need to reinstall the OEM copy. And Windows only installs in UEFI mode to gpt partitioned drives, did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode on a gpt partitioned drive? Windows 7 default install is BIOS only from DVD, which then you need a separate product key to legally install it.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't help you with installing Windows, I can help you with the partitioning.

Boot from an Ubuntu LiveCD or USB and choose "Try Ubuntu".  GParted is installed by default.  Fire up GParted and it will show you your partitions.  From here you're able to shrink your Linux partition.  Shrink it enough so you have enough room for Windows and whatever extra amount of free space you'll need.  Create a new NTFS Partition to fill up the free space.

From this point on, I would consult someone on SuperUser or elsewhere as someone else mentioned.